# The broadcast receiver's lifecycycle?Why my service gone?

Tags: android

My app runs in background. I use alarmmanager to trig a alarm every minutes.When my Broadcast receiver receive the alarm I start a service.But I found that the service only last for about 4~5 seconds.I think every time the alarmmanager trig a alarm and a new Broadcast receiver instance created.the Broadcast receiver goes quickly.So the service gone with it?But the android.os.Proccess.myPid() is always the same.I am confusing with it.
Thanks,
zhangkai

Comment: It would be helpful to debug the problem, if you share the code.

Comment: code please ? post your code here  and explain what exactly is the problem .

Comment: sorry for that I do not report my code with the question.The code is here.[link](https://github.com/GisKook/gpstracker)

Comment: @Jickson I am confusing with the behavior with the service start in broadcast receiver.It seems that the broadcast receiver start every 30 seconds. the service is belong to the broadcast receiver proccess.But the broadcast receiver goes immediately.I wrote a [simple code] (https://github.com/GisKook/testservice)

Comment: @zhangkai I have checked the code of MyService.java class. You are calling Thread.sleep inside onStartCommand function. In android, Service will run in UI thread. By calling Thread.sleep, you are blocking UI thread for more than 5 seconds. So the Android system will show ANR.

Comment: @zhangkai If you want to perform some long calculation in background then you should IntentService. Let me know if this resolves the problem you are facing.

Comment: @Jickson in my [code](https://github.com/GisKook/gpstracker/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/zhangkai/gpstraker) I start a service in broadcast receiver.Then I start a HandlerThread in that service.I think the service will last long.But when my app in background the service seems gone for a faw seconds.So I block the onStartCommand function.Do you know why my service not last long?It it killed by android?

Comment: @zhangkai I see few issues in the current implementation after going through the code. Suggest a channel to communicate so that I can help you more in resolving the issues.

Comment: @Jickson I have adjust my code.It seems when I request location in background.The service will gone.It is because the mobile manufacturer custom the rom.Now I remove all my blocking operation in UI thread.Thanks for you reply.